# Else statement doesn't work in "Click" event when I try to toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner at Javascript and I've been having trouble trying to toggle the size of my 3d carousel menu that I have created.

The menu starts large in the centre of the screen and I would like it to shrink and move to the top-left corner when I click on it and when I click it again it will enlarge and go back to its initial position.

Right now, the way the big menu shrinks and moves to the top-left corner is working just as I wished, however, the else statement inside my cellTransform() function is not executing so it's not returning to its original state when clicked again.

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jcou6gre/3/

Below is my code:
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>carousel menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="carousel" id="carousel">
        <!-- cell 1 -->
        <div class="carousel-cell cell1" id="carousel-cell">
          <div class="cell-text-wrapper">
            <div class="cell-text">

              Upload image
              <br>
              Save
              <br>
              Submit

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- cell 2 -->
        <div class="carousel-cell cell2" id="carousel-cell">
          <div class="cell-text-wrapper">
            <div class="cell-text">

              Gallery

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- cell 3 -->
        <div class="carousel-cell cell3" id="carousel-cell">
          <div class="cell-text-wrapper">
            <div class="cell-text">

              TIPS

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- cell 4 -->
        <div class="carousel-cell cell4" id="carousel-cell">
          <div class="cell-text-wrapper">
            <div class="cell-text">

              About

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;

  left:30vw;
  top:30vh;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;

  transform: rotateZ(-20deg) rotateY(25deg) rotateX(-30deg) ;
}

.carousel-cell {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.cell-text-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell-text{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial ;
}

.cell1 {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform: rotateY(  0deg) rotateX( 10deg) translateZ(250px);
}


.cell2 {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(300px);
}

.cell3 {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg) rotateX( 10deg) translateZ(250px);
}

.cell4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(300px);
}
```

JS:

```
// TOGGLE LARGE SMALL MENU
$(".menu").click(function() {
  if ($(".carousel-cell").height() != 30) {
    $(".carousel-cell").animate({
      height: 30,
      width: 50,
    }, 1000);
    $(".cell-text").animate({
      fontSize: "10px"
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $(".carousel-cell").animate({
      height: 300,
      width: 500,
    }, 1000);
    $(".cell-text").animate({
      fontSize: "20px"
    }, 1000);
  }

});


function cellTransform() {
  var cell1 = document.querySelector(".cell1");
  var cell2 = document.querySelector(".cell2");
  var cell3 = document.querySelector(".cell3");
  var cell4 = document.querySelector(".cell4");

  if (cell1.style.transform != "translateZ(50px)") {
    cell1.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
    cell1.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(50px)";
    cell2.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
    cell2.style.transform = "rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px)";
    cell3.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
    cell3.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(50px)";
    cell4.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
    cell4.style.transform = "rotateY(270deg) translateZ(50px)";

    document.querySelector(".menu").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.left = "8vw";
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.top = "10vh";

    document.querySelector(".carousel").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
    document.querySelector(".carousel").style.width = "10%";
    document.querySelector(".carousel").style.height = "10%";
  } else if (cell2.style.transform == "translateZ(50px)") {
    cell1.style.transition = "transform 2.5s ease-in 1s";
    cell1.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(250px)";
    cell2.style.transition = "transform 2.5s ease-in 1s";
    cell2.style.transform = "rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px)";
    cell3.style.transition = "transform 2.5s ease-in 1s";
    cell3.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(250px)";
    cell4.style.transition = "transform 2.5s ease-in 1s";
    cell4.style.transform = "rotateY(270deg) translateZ(300px)";

    document.querySelector(".menu").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.left = "30vw";
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.top = "30vh";

    document.querySelector(".carousel").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
    document.querySelector(".carousel").style.width = "100%";
    document.querySelector(".carousel").style.height = "100%";
  }


}

document.querySelector(".menu").addEventListener("click", cellTransform, false);
```

Any helps is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergio has said, the transform value does not only contain the translateZ property but also other properties, you should use the `includes()` or `indexOf()` function. `includes()` works fine here easier to read, though. This code works in your JSFiddle:

```
if (!cell2.style.transform.includes("translateZ(50px)")) {
  cell1.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
  cell1.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(50px)";
  cell2.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
  cell2.style.transform = "rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px)";
  cell3.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
  cell3.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(50px)";
  cell4.style.transition = "transform 1.0s linear 0s";
  cell4.style.transform = "rotateY(270deg) translateZ(50px)";

  document.querySelector(".menu").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.left = "8vw";
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.top = "10vh";

  document.querySelector(".carousel").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
  document.querySelector(".carousel").style.width = "10%";
  document.querySelector(".carousel").style.height = "10%";
} else if (cell2.style.transform.includes("translateZ(50px)")) {
  cell1.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in 0s";
  cell1.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(250px)";
  cell2.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in 0s";
  cell2.style.transform = "rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px)";
  cell3.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in 0s";
  cell3.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg) rotateX(10deg) translateZ(250px)";
  cell4.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in 0s";
  cell4.style.transform = "rotateY(270deg) translateZ(300px)";

  document.querySelector(".menu").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.left = "30vw";
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.top = "30vh";

  document.querySelector(".carousel").style.transition = "all 1s ease-in 0s";
  document.querySelector(".carousel").style.width = "100%";
  document.querySelector(".carousel").style.height = "100%";
}
```

The changes I made are:

- change the conditions to use includes function instead of equals symbols. Also for future uses, in JS you should use `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. This is due to JS interpreting all values as truthy and falsy if `==` and `!=` are used. This can lead to some confusing situations like `if ("false" == true) {..} // <- code in if statement is executet`. This is advanced knowledge, for further reading take a look at [this](https://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/07/advanced-javascript-operators-and-truthy-falsy/).
- use the same cell to check the transform value.
- change the transformation duration in the else to `transform 1s ease-in 0s` to make it more smooth (optional). Without this you'll have a two step animation with first zooming in on the menu and then rearange them to have a squarey arrangement instead of a hashtagy arrangement.

In addition to that, I'd recommend to put all the styles in matching css classes. On button click you can then toggle a css class for an element. JQuery has a method for this. 
This makes the code more readable because you don't merge style and logic code. Also it helps you to track the different styles you apply for each state.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your detailed explanation! This is so so helpful. I will try to clean up my code with putting the styles in css. Thanks again for all information!

Answer (score 0):

If you log cell2.style.transform you get

- ""
- "rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px)"

You should test if it includes the translate property, not if it's exact match.
Actually, you are having the same issue in the first IF statement as it also is empty or it's a string with 3 properties.

You should use [String.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) method or [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf) (indexOf has full support, includes doesn't).